# Runtime Error in using function call by reference?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class defined as,

```
class dimension{
public:
    dimension();
    const char* getname();
    long ing getlength();
    void setname(const char* text)
    void setlength(long int size)
    virtual ~dimension();
private:
    const char* name;
    long int length;
}
```

I am getting error regarding the functions `setname` and `setlength` are of importance so their definitions are as,

```
void dimension::setname(const char* text)
{
    dimension::name = text;
}
void dimension::setlength(long int size)
{
    dimension::length = size;    
}
```

Now i have 2 functions which i am using to read an array of objects of class dimension from a file. Their definition is as.

```
void read_dimension(dimension** dims, int*ndims, const char* text, long int size)
{
    int i;
    *dims = new dimension[*ndims];
    for(i=0; i<ndims; i++)
    {
        (*dims)[i].setname(text)   
        (*dims)[i].setlength(size) 
    }
}

void read_file(char *path, dimension** dims, int *ndims)
{
    //do-- open file and read the variables ndims, text and size from it.
    read_dimension(dims, ndims, text, size);
    //do-- print name and length of all elements of (*dims).
}
```

Now, i am calling these functions in **main** as

```
int main()
{
    //do-- get file path
    dimesnion* gdims;
    int num_dims;
    read_file(path, &gdims, &num_dims);
    //do-- print name and length of each element of gdims.
    return 0;
}
```

When i run the code the variable `"name"` printed from the the functions `read_dimension()` and `main()` are different but the variable `"length"` is the same.
I can't figure out why this is happening.
I would be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: Where is text declared in function read_dimension ?

Comment: The `read_dimension` you posted seems to be truncated. In particular, where does the variable `text` come from? Be aware that `name` is just a char pointer, so if you delete the underlying array after leaving `read_dimension`, `name` will point to garbage.

Comment: Why not use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead?

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile. Please post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @ComicSansMS, okay got the problem...when i leave the function read() the pointer to name is deleted, thanks...!!

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, i am working on writing a similar code with vectors but i am getting a different problem,
    vector<dimension> dims;
    dimension d;
    d.setname(text);
    d.setlength(size);
    dims.push_back(d);
    cout<<dims[0].getname();
when use this code in the read dimension function, null is printed in the ternminal.

Answer (score 0):

There's no doubts text is a local variable in read_dimension function, probably an array of char. dimension::setname assigns one pointer to another, as already mentioned, what happens when text variable in read_dimension function goes out of scope? It'll die... Now your pointer in dimension class points to "nowhere". 
I prefer to use const char * as string literals or as pointer to some char in array of chars. If you want to store a string you'd copy it via strcpy maybe, of course destination array of char with sufficient space must exists.

What's the purpose of this code: dimension::name = text; and dimension::length = size; in setname and setlength methods? You're in the scope of dimension class, aren't you?

Comment: thanks, i got the problem once i go out of the scope of read_dimension the pointer points to nowhere. and about that other thing, i was using variable name "name" and "length" instead of text and size, so for my own clarity i wrote dimension::name = name

Comment: I see. In addition you can use this pointer in your no static methods to access some members if they are hidden with parameters.